# HTTP status codes which don't allow to return a message body

Tags: http, http-status-codes

Is there any other HTTP status code beside 204 which don't allow to return  a message body.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. [RFC 7230, section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3) states:

> The presence of a message body in a response depends on both the request method to which it is responding and the response status code

The section makes also clear that *all* [1xx-class](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.2) responses as well as responses with the status codes 204 and 304 are supposed to have no message body.

Responses to `HEAD` request are also expected to never have a body.